# Reading config item and using `IOptions<T>` failing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, configuration

I don't get it! I'd swear I'm following the documentation ([Options pattern in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-5.0)) to the letter, yet once I get into my service, the option value is null.

Here's the `appsettings.json` file contents;

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConfigStrings": {
    "IDProofingQuestionsPath": "C:\\dev\\...\\wwwroot\\sample-data\\idProofingQuestionsMOCK.json"
  }
}
```

(And just so you know, this path is for testing some stuff, it's not going to be permanent.)

Here's my `ConfigureServices()` method.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // IDProofingQuestionsPathOptions.IDProofingQuestionsPath <- Section:Option string for the Settings file.
    services.Configure<IDProofingQuestionsPathOptions>(Configuration.GetSection(IDProofingQuestionsPathOptions.IDProofingQuestionsPath));

    // This is the service into which I'm trying to inject this 'Option'
    services.AddScoped<IIDProofingServices, IDProofingServices>();

    services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

    services.AddSession(options =>
    {
        options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    });

    services.AddControllersWithViews();
}
```

And here's the code for my service, into which I'm trying to inject the `IDProofingQuestionsPathOptions` instance.

```
public class IDProofingServices : IIDProofingServices
{
    private readonly string _proofingQuestionsPath;

    /// <summary>
    /// This is a parameterized constructor for allowing Dependency Injection
    /// </summary>
    public IDProofingServices(
        IOptions<IDProofingQuestionsPathOptions> proofingQuestionsPath)
    {
        if (proofingQuestionsPath == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(proofingQuestionsPath));
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(proofingQuestionsPath.Value.IdProofingQuestionsPath))
        {
            // my code ends up here, and I just do NOT get what I'm doing wrong.
            throw new ArgumentNullException("proofingQuestionsPath.Value.IdProofingQuestionsPath");
        }

        _proofingQuestionsPath = proofingQuestionsPath.Value.IdProofingQuestionsPath;
    }

    ...
```

Oh, and of course the option(s) object.

```
public class IDProofingQuestionsPathOptions
{
    public const string IDProofingQuestionsPath = "ConfigStrings:IDProofingQuestionsPath";

    public string IdProofingQuestionsPath { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: IDProofingQuestionsPath looks like a property under section ConfigStrings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Configure`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.optionsconfigurationservicecollectionextensions.configure?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) method expects a configuration section *object*, but your call to [`GetSection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.iconfiguration.getsection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) only offers a *string* value without any children which could be bound to the options object.

A straightforward fix would be binding directly to the `ConfigStrings` property, or introducing a JSON wrapper for your path property.

---

Small minimized example for the latter solution:

**Startup**:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Bind to the 'MyPathOptions' wrapper object
    services.Configure<PathOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("ConfigStrings:MyPathOptions"));

    // ...
}
```

**PathOptions**:

```cs
public class PathOptions
{
    public string MyPath { get; set; }
}
```

**appsettings.json**:

```js
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConfigStrings": {
    "MyPathOptions": {
      "MyPath": "abc"
    }
  }
}
```

**TestController**:

```cs
[Route("")]
public class TestController : Controller
{
    private readonly IOptions<PathOptions> _pathOptions;

    public TestController(IOptions<PathOptions> pathOptions)
    {
        _pathOptions = pathOptions ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(pathOptions));
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return Ok(_pathOptions);
    }
}
```

Comment: :facepalm: I swear, something in my head knew that was the issue, but I wasn't at a point at which I could really test/verify. Thanks!!

Comment: Well shoot! This fix worked for my side-project, but the code I've shown in this question is still not working, and I've definitely added the 'Key' string as `"ConfigStrings:" + IDProofingQuestionsPathOptions.IdProofingQuestionsPathKey` :(

Comment: Okay, added the extra level as shown in the Answer (e.g. `ConfigStrings:MyPathOptions` ABOVE the actual value k/v) and that finally did it!